# In how many ways can you construct an array of size N such that the product of any pair of consecutive elements in not greater than M?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Every element is an integer and should have a value of at least 1.

Constraints: 2 ≤ N ≤ 1000 and 1 ≤ M ≤ 1000000000.

We need to find the answer modulo 1000000007

Comment: What are your initial thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Use dynamic programming.

Comment: well, if an element has a value of `x`, if the value `x` is lesser or equal to `sqrt(M)` then the next value can be equal to or greater than `sqrt(M)` and vice versa. This might help us to get a so called 'state' in dynamic programming but I am unsure of how to proceed or if this is feasible.

Comment: Given `M`, call integers `i,j ≥ 1` *equivalent* if, for all integers `k ≥ 1`, it is the case that `ik ≤ M` if and only if `jk ≤ M`. How many equivalence classes are there?

Comment: All I can think of is O(n^n) is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

May be we can calculate dp[len][type][typeValue], where type have only two states:

type = 0: this is means, that last number in sequence with length *len* equal or smaller than `sqrt(M)`. And this number we save in *typeValue*

type = 1: this is means, that last number in sequence bigger than `sqrt(M)`. And we save in *typeValue* number `k = M / lastNumber` (rounded down), which not greater than `sqrt(M)`.

So, this dp have `O(N sqrt(M))` states, but how can we calculate each 'cell' of this dp?

Firstly, consider some 'cell' dp[len][0][number]. This value can calculate as follows:

`dp[len][0][number] = sum[1 <= i <= sqrt(M)] (dp[len - 1][0][i]) + sum[number <= i <= sqrt(M)] (dp[len - 1][1][i])`

Little explanation: beacuse `type = 0` => `number <= sqrt(M)`, so we can put any number not greater than `sqrt(M)` next and only some small number greater.

For the dp[len][1][number] we can use next equation:
`dp[len][1][k] = sum[1 <= i <= k] (dp[len - 1][0][i] * cntInGroup(k))` where `cntInGroup(k)` - cnt numbers `x` such that `M / x = k`

We can simply calculate `cntInGroups(k)` for all `1 <= k <= sqrt(M)` using binary search or formulas.

But another problem is that out algorithm needs `O(sqrt(M))` operations so result asymptotic is `O(N M)`. But we can improve that.

Note that we need to calculate sum of some values on **segments**, which were processed on previous step. So, we can precalculate prefix sums in advance and after that we can calculate each 'cell' of dp in `O(1)` time.

So, with this optimization we can solve this problem with asymptotic `O(N sqrt(M))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for N = 4, M = 10:

```
1 number divides 10 into 10 equal parts with a remainder less than the part
1 number divides 10 into 5 equal parts with a remainder less than the part
1 number divides 10 into 3 equal parts with a remainder less than the part
2 numbers divide 10 into 2 equal parts with a remainder less than the part
5 numbers divide 10 into 1 part with a remainder less than the part

Make an array and update it for each value of n:

N  1   1   1   2   5
----------------------
2  10  5   3   2   1    // 10 div 1           ; 10 div 2      ; 10 div 3 ; 10 div 5,4 ; 10 div 6,7,8,9,10
3  27  22  18  15  10   // 10+5+3+2*2+5*1     ; 10+5+3+2*2    ; 10+5+3   ; 10+5       ; 10
4  147 97  67  49  27   // 27+22+18+2*15+5*10 ; 27+22+18+2*15 ; 27+22+18 ; 27+22      ; 27

The solution for N = 4, M = 10 is therefore:
147 + 97 + 67 + 2*49 + 5*27 = 544
```

My thought process:

```
For each number in the first array position, respectively, there could be the 
following in the second:

1  ->  1,2..10
2  ->  1,2..5
3  ->  1,2,3
4  ->  1,2
5  ->  1,2
6  ->  1
7  ->  1
8  ->  1
9  ->  1
10 ->  1

Array position 3:
For each of 10 1's in col 2, there could be 1 of 1,2..10
For each of 5 2's in col 2, there could be 1 of 1,2..5
For each of 3 3's in col 2, there could be 1 of 1,2,3
For each of 2 4's in col 2, there could be 1 of 1,2
For each of 2 5's in col 2, there could be 1 of 1,2
For each of 1 6,7..10 in col 2, there could be one 1
27 1's; 22 2's; 18 3's; 15 4's; 15 5's; 10 x 6's,7's,8's,9's,10's

Array position 4:
1's = 27+22+18+15+15+10*5
2's = 27+22+18+15+15
3's = 27+22+18
4's = 27+22
5's = 27+22
6,7..10's = 27 each
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a graph and assign the values from 0 to M to the vertices. An edge exists between two vertices if their product is not greater than M. The number of different arrays is then the number of paths with N steps, starting at the vertex with value 0. This number can be computed using a simple depth-first search.

The question is now whether this is efficient enough and whether it can be made more efficient. One way is to restructure the solution using matrix multiplication. The matrix to multiply with represents the edges above, it has a 1 when there is an edge, a 0 otherwise. The initial matrix on the left represents the starting vertex, it has a 1 at position (0, 0), zeros everywhere else.

Based on this, you can multiply the right matrix with itself to represent two steps through the graph. This means that you can combine two steps to make them more efficient, so you only need to multiply log(N) times, not N times. However, make sure you use known efficient matrix multiplication algorithms to implement this, the naive one will only perform for small M.